# Attempt to create table ingnored or not executed postgresql

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

Im trying set up postgresql but every time I try make a Table:

`CREATE TABLE player (discord_id, game_id, game_username)`

It does nothing no errors. Then when I do `\dt` to list tables it says this:

```
roblox=# \dt
Did not find any relations.
```

Why can't I create a table?

Comment: You did end the command with a semi-colon?

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: No error message in the console

Comment: @SteveTurczyn It errors with `syntax error at or near ";"` when i do it with semi-colon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the type you want the columns to be in Postgres. Postgres doesn't assume what type of data you are passing it unless you explicitly tell it.

```
CREATE TABLE player (discord_id int, game_id int, game_username varchar);
```

For example. Here are the docs on this function https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-createtable.html

Here is a [list](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/datatype.html) of all the data types in Postgres